# Scale/inflate part of mesh along curve

Tags: mesh, bezier-curves, transforms, surface-deform

I have a mesh with tree-like branches. I want to create a curve which resembles loosly the shape and make an empty follow that curve.

Is it possible to scale/inflate the part of main object from zero to full size as the empty passes it's position?
The linked video shows growing branches, which use the option to create thickness to a curve. Instead of thickness I want to "grow" an existing mesh.

[Example growing branches](https://player.vimeo.com/video/79367387)

Comment: you can use a Lattice to inflate a shape but maybe you should give a bit more details

Comment: @moonboots I added a video link in my posting.

Comment: this is probably made with a curve, a Taper object, enable Map Taper and play with the Start & End Mapping values: zupimages.net/up/21/43/cf2e.gif is it what you're looking for and do you need an explanation? But no empty here